# Can one PC be used by two users at the same time via dual-monitor?

Tags: x11, users, keyboard, multi-monitor, multiseat

Since modern PCs can use two screens at the same time I wonder if it is possible to plug in two keyboards and mouses as well to have the two screens run two (more or less) independent X-sessions at once?

Comment: related: [Setting up a multiseat configuration](http://superuser.com/q/29879/35237) (@SU)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In short, yes, this is possible.  The relevant search string you are looking for is "Multi-seat X".

The [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX), [Gentoo wiki](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/HOWTO_Multiseat_X), [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Multi_Seat_Debian_HOWTO) and [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat) all have articles related to multi-seat X.  A number of other articles can be found on the [Xorg wiki page on multiseat](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat) and even more can be found on google.

From what I can tell from these articles, there are two ways to do this:

- Multiple X servers, or
- Using Xephyr on top of Xorg.

Which of these methods will work for you will depend on the version of Xorg you are running and your hardware. Multiple X servers seem to be the easier route if your hardware setup supports it. There is also work to be done with the display manager, sound server, and other components -- much of which is covered in the various articles linked above.

Additionally, there is a [multiseat display manager (MDM)](http://wiki.c3sl.ufpr.br/multiseat/index.php/Mdm) to automate these configurations. It's not yet integrated in most distributions, though (the `mdm` package in Ubuntu is a homonym).

Comment: awesome, I'll try that soon, thanks! will it work with hardware acceleration (openGL)?

Comment: @Tobias, I'm not sure.  I don't immediately think there would be a problem, but that is just a hunch.

Comment: sounds great, now I [only have to get it setup](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5429/863)...

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't ever get this running :/ Back when this question was still open I actually ended up with a VM, see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14845/88

Answer (score 0):

Multiseat is one way to go. But if you want to have 2 mice (or 2 keyboards, or both) with different input streams directed simultaneously to 2 different terminals, you can use xinput: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multi-pointer_X

commands you need (self explanatory):

> xinput list
> xinput create-master [name]
> xinput reattach [slave device name or id] [master device name or id]

I had to reattach my mouse/keyboard AFTER creating the master. Maybe it was just a glitch...

What worked on my side: I had 2 mice, 2 keyboard, 2 terminals:

- focusing terminal-A with mouse-A
- focusing terminal-B with mouse-B
- typing keyboard-A showed the output on terminal-A
- typing keyboard-B showed the output on terminal-B