# Lock second mouse pointer & keyboard input to one window

Tags: xorg, gnome, multiseat

This is basically a lite version of multiseat (see [my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5251/863)): I can setup two mouse pointers (see e.g. [here](http://blog.danyul.id.au/?p=128), [here](http://ao2.it/en/blog/2010/01/19/poor-mans-multi-touch-using-multiple-mice-xorg) or [here](http://ankurs.com/2010/10/multiple-mouse-keyboard-in-linux/)) and two keyboards (although my two identical logitech K200 keyboards show up as *four* keyboards in `xinput list`, any ideas why?). Only this is not enough to allow two users to do things independently, since apparently only one window can be focused at a time so all keyboard input goes to that window. Can this behaviour be changed?

Can the inputs of two keyboards be directed to two different windows at the same time? And can a mouse-locking application be told to only lock *one* of the pointers?

(in case your answer includes `Xephyr`, can that support direct open gl rendering?)

Comment: Same question for Windows 7: http://superuser.com/q/230210/35237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB keyboards often expose multiple interfaces; it is likely that one is the standard 104-key set and another is the extra buttons.

[MPWM](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/mpwm/) is a simple window manager that is able to use the MPX extensions to allow for multiple independent client pointers and active windows.  You'll have to wait for similar support to appear in other window managers.

Xephyr currently supports neither direct nor indirect OpenGL rendering.  It's [in development](http://gitorious.org/xephyr-with-gl-acceleration).

Comment: I wouldn't mind testing a different WM. However, MPWM doesn't show up on the gdm menu, is there anything else I need to do after a successful `sudo make install`?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning MPWM and the link to xephyir-with-gl size. [This blog entry from 2007](http://dodji.blogspot.com/2007/10/xephyr-xvideo-and-gl-has-landed.html) claims Xephyr would support OpenGL, which seems to [part of xserver's master branch](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=604ebb5a6de372e6a8a96e0ee997db7929126860), but what to do with this? Would I need a new compile of Xserver?

Comment: @Tobias: MPWM isn't really integrated into anything and I wouldn't recommend using it for anything other than testing, but you can kill your existing window manager and just start `mpwm`.  The GL support in upstream Xephyr isn't accelerated.  You can compile just the Xephyr server from that xserver branch.