# One machine & two keyboard, mouse & monitors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-monitor, multiseat, multiuser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one PC be used by two users at the same time via dual-monitor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/can-one-pc-be-used-by-two-users-at-the-same-time-via-dual-monitor)

I have a machine that is running Ubuntu.
Can I have two monitors, mouses & keyboards for two different users to use this machine at the same time?
What additional hardwares do I need? (e.g. two display adapters?)
What configurations should I do?

Thanks

Comment: You could run the thing as a "Desktop Server" using something like VNC or XSession forwarding, but that would require each user to have their own dedicated machine separate from the machine you describe. Viable?

Comment: "multiseat" is the keyword for this kind of configuration. I can't give any advice on how to do it but the keyword should help you in your search for documentation

Comment: @Tim: as I heard Linux and X can handle this; and for two users I don't think I make any problem (both users are restricted to user certain applications)

Comment: The [X.Org page on Multiseat](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat) is a good place to start.