# Outputting sound from different monitors to different audio devices

Tags: kde, nvidia, pulseaudio, hdmi

I have got my computer set up in my living room on a desk with the TV 1 metre away. I want to be able to use my TV to watch videos from my computer. I am using Chakra Linux, I use the NVIDIA binary drivers and KDE 4.11.2.

I'd like to have both screens attached to my computer at all times. I want to be able to drag windows to the corners of each screen to use the automatic resize option and I want to have applications on each screen output to different audio devices.

I have attempted to use different X-server sessions for each screen, which has opened up a can of worms.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: *"I have attempted to use different X-server sessions for each screen"* -> why?  I'm kinda dubious that is even possible.

Comment: If you go into the nvidia-settings, it gives you an option to do so.

I thought it might be easier to send audio outputs from each X session to different hardware. It is difficult in KDE to have each session run programmes. 

For example, firefox refuses to run on multiple x-servers (at least using the same profile). When I attempt to shut down on Session 1, Session 0 loads the shutdown menu.

It means that when I drag to the corners of the screen, it does the auto-resize thing. I cannot drag applications between sessions. But the mouse can go between.

Comment: Okay.  I don't think doing that will help with the sound though, because pulseaudio is configured either system wide or per user, and you still only have one user.  I'd think there is some way to do this via pulseaudio though.  If you don't get an answer, try their mailing list: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Community/ ...and of course if you figure it out, post your own answer here.

Comment: Another possibility inspired by a concurrent question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/can-one-pc-be-used-by-two-users-at-the-same-time-via-dual-monitor if you are willing to make the two sessions owned by different users.  Unfortunately, it looks like pulseaudio  might not co-operate with that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192522/how-do-i-configure-sound-with-pulseaudio-and-multiseat  But plain ALSA *might*.