# How can I set up multiseat/separate X sessions with gnome 3?

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome3, multi-monitor

With classic Gnome, if one had two monitors, one could set up "separate X sessions" for each monitor.  In this configuration, each monitor had a separate user login session and application windows were captive to the X session they were launched from.  Is something similar possible with Gnome 3?  If so, how do you go about setting it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the desktop environment you are going to use an [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5255/19575) remains valid.

Basically you need to gather the names Xorg uses/gives your devices and monitors, then you combine devices and monitors to "seats". In `xorg.conf` terminology seats are "ServerLayout" sections. Then you reconfigure your display manager to start multiple instances, each using a different ServerLayout.

The ServerLayout sections will look something like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "seatX"
    Screen      X  "ScreenX" 0 0
    InputDevice    "MouseX" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "KeyboardX" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "seatY"
    Screen      Y  "ScreenY" 0 0
    InputDevice    "MouseY" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "KeyboardY" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```

and to reconfigure gdm, its configuration file will look something like this

```
 [servers]
 0=Standard0
 1=Standard1
 ...

 [server-Standard0]
 name=Standard server
 command=/usr/X11R6/bin/X -novtswitch -sharevts -layout seatX

 [server-Standard1]
 name=Standard server
 command=/usr/X11R6/bin/X -novtswitch -sharevts -layout seatY
```

[note]: shamelessly copied from the Gentoo Wiki