# Segmentation fault when trying to run glxgears via virtualGL

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault

(Follow-up on [How to efficiently use 3D via a remote connection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5235/863))

I installed the amd64 package on the server and the i386 one on the client. Following [the user's guide](http://www.virtualgl.org/vgldoc/2_2final/#hd007001) I run this on the client:

```
me@client> /opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglconnect me@server
me@server> /opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun glxgears
```

This causes a segfault, using `vglconnect -s` for a ssh tunnel doesn't work either. I also tried the [TurboVNC method](http://www.virtualgl.org/vgldoc/1_0final/#hd008001), where starting `vglrun glxgears` works, but I'd prefer transmitting only the application window using the jpeg compression. Is the problem 32 <-> 64 bit? Or how can I fix things?

Comment: That might be it. But this is new, bleeding edge stuff so expect bugs. You can help by filing a bug at the project site.

Comment: you can install 32bits x/gl/libc libs and run it with `linux32 /opt/VirtualGL/bin/vglrun glxgears`. This will allow you to know if problem comes from 32 <-> 64 bit.

Comment: For debugging segfaults, you chould find out which binary segfaults and run it with strace/ltrace or gdb. That might tell you how far it gets and what it tries to do before dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how this remote 3D works but if the client is indeed trying to run the amd64 executable, this is definitely the reason this message appears.